# When I read PDF from URL it shows English data correctly but other language text is not Properly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

This code Convert only English PDF code in English text, And I want to Convert Any other Language to English, So how  can, I Solve this Problem.

Below is my code

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;   
private string PDFReader(string url)
{
     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
       PdfReader pdfReader;       

          try
            {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            url = "http://www.openprocurement.al/tenders/shpallje/29357.pdf";
            pdfReader = new PdfReader(url);
              for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
               {
                 ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                 string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                 if (currentText.Contains("Page " + page.ToString()))
                  {
                   currentText = currentText.Replace("Page " + page.ToString(), "♥♥");
                  }
                  currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                  text.Append(currentText);
               }
                    pdfReader.Close();

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

           }

         return text.Replace("â€˜", "‘").Replace("â€™", "’").Replace("â€“", "–").ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Your own code mangles the text. Strings in .NET are Unicode. They don't need any kind of decoding or codepage conversion. The line `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Conv...` guarantees garbled text. Just delete it. Also remove all the replacements at the end - those strings were created by the "decoding" line

Answer (score 0):

.NET strings are Unicode, specifically UTF16. They don't need any kind of conversion.

The problems are *caused* by the attempt to convert Unicode to the local machine's locale then back to Unicode as if it were UTF8 (which it isn't, it's in the local machine's locale). That's what produces the `â€` strings too - the two-byte UTF8 sequences are translated as ASCII (most likely Western European).

This code extracts the text without any conversion issues :

```
static  string GetPdfText(string url)
{
    var separator="\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    var text = new StringBuilder();                            
    var  strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

    using( var pdfReader = new PdfReader(url))
    {
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            var  currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            text.Append(separator);
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
    }
    return text.ToString();     
}
```

Comment: http://www.openprocurement.al/tenders/shpallje/29357.pdf    

I am Providing  You Link , I want data as it is that was given in the link, (In Link There is one PDF Page)

Comment: Did you try the code? I used that URL and got back the file. The format isn't the same because simple text *doesn't* contain formatting or spacing. If you get multiple spaces it's because that's what `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` returns.

Comment: In any case PDF isn't a text format and the order different text parts appear in the file has little to do with how they appear in the page

Comment: I Tried Your Solution , Its Working On My Project, But There is a Issue. The Issue is the Collected data fomat is not proper i want proper Format like the given on the link, but i unable to do that.
I have one Diffrent Source "https://ireps.gov.in/ireps/supply/pdfdocs/092019/105066688/viewNitPdf_2936637.pdf"

this link is the Source, 
In This Link I Got accurate result that i want ,
So i need help for Proper Formating and spaceing, And text is missing , So How Can I Solve this issue 
Please suggest 

Link That i Want - http://www.openprocurement.al/tenders/shpallje/29357.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

[Using the WhatsMate PDF-to-Text REST API](https://whatsmate.github.io/2017-06-08-convert-pdf-to-text-csharp/)